# Is quorum disk required for standalone installations?

Tags: storage-area-network, oracle, oraclevm

A provider is setting up a single bare-metal Oracle server for us, which will not be part of any grid or cluster. It has over 20 disks connected via fiber to a SAN, each 1TB.
OVM is installed on a remote redhat server and the bare metal has Oracle linux with OVS.

Is the quorum disk really obligatory? It is my understanding that it requires a small dedicated disk, but the smallest disk I have is 1TB and it would be a terrible waste-

If you could please send links to the documentation which states that it is (or isn't) I would greatly appreciate it.

I have my concerns if the provider is over engineering.

Thanks

Comment: This is setting off alarm-bells for me - about 15 years ago this was the advised way to do Oracle clusters - lots of little LUNs - it drove me mad, I needed a spreadsheet to record it all. Then last time we built some clusters things had changed and our DBAs had left and been replaced and all of a sudden they were happy with fewer and bigger LUNs - something tells me you're dealing with someone not up to date here. That said which array manufacturer has a 1TB minimum LUN size? I've not heard of that before, 1GB sure but not 1TB, never seen that.

Comment: This might be better answered on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Its for cluster only setup. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E58626_01/html/E84120/grmeh.html

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HABPT/config_rac.htm#HABPT4874

Answer (score 2):

First, OVM is not a supported platform any more.
The replacement is Oracle Linux Virtualization Manager (OLVM) which is based on ovirt.

Now, if you still plan to use OVM then a quorum disk is required. As OVM is based on a cluster file system which needs a Quorum disk. Doesn't matter if there is a single host in the cluster.

With OLVM However you don't need a quorum disk. So maybe it is better to look into the current product and not the outdated one.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need a quorum disk for a single OVS host. I've installed several OVS hosts with local storage repos and no server pool filesystem myself. Example (hostname edited):

```
[root@ovshost01 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1              50G  2.4G   45G   5% /
tmpfs                 2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2             477M   81M  367M  18% /boot
/dev/sda1             200M  9.8M  190M   5% /boot/efi
none                  2.9G  232K  2.9G   1% /var/lib/xenstored
/dev/mapper/OVM_SYS_REPO_PART_3600062b2025dc2c027dccc2a6cbcac8d
                      3.2T  3.1T   73G  98% /OVS/Repositories/0004fb0000030000c4ac35277620e133
[root@ovshost01 ~]#
```

It's an unusual configuration because it negates most of the benefits of using OVM, but it's quite possible.

OVM has been superseded by OLVM, as already commented. It is still supported by Oracle, though.